# Select precisely the departure of a line between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, anchor

I want to chose the departure of my lines between my nodes in somewhere between these anchors, for example I want to choose a anchor between north east and east. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[papersize={216mm,330mm},tmargin=20mm,bmargin=20mm,lmargin=20mm,rmargin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes.multipart,shapes,fit}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{float}

\tikzset{
    basic/.style={
        draw,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        rectangle split part fill={blue!20,white},
        text width=0.3\textwidth,
        align=center,
        font=\itshape
    },
    Ellipse/.style={
        ellipse, 
        draw, 
        shape aspect=2, 
        inner sep=5pt,
        text centered,
        fill=blue!10!white,
        font=\itshape
    },
    splitEllipse/.style={
        draw, 
        fill=blue!10!white,
        shape=ellipse split,
        align=center,
        minimum width=1cm,
        inner sep=5pt,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=0.5}]
\node[basic] (Abonné) {Abonné
        \nodepart{second}
        \underline{IdA}\\
        Nom\\
        Prénom\\
        Date de Naissance
        };
    \node[Ellipse, above right= 0.1cm and 1.5cm of Abonné] (Adhère) {Adhère};
    \node[basic, below right= 0.1cm and 1.5
cm of Adhère] (Club) {Club
        \nodepart{second}
        \underline{NumClub}\\
        Nom\\
        Adresse\\
        };
 \node[splitEllipse, below right= 0.2cm and 1.2cm of Abonné] (Evènement) {Evènement};
     \node[Ellipse, below right= 0cm and 3.5cm of Evènement] (Implante) {Implante};
  \node[basic, below left= 0.1cm and 0.7cm of Implante] (Ville) {Ville
        \nodepart{second}
        \underline{CP}\\
        Nom\\
        Superficie\\
        };
       \node[basic, below= 0.7cm of Abonné] (Activité) {Activité
        \nodepart{second}
        \underline{NumActivité}\\
        Nom\\ 
        Prix\\
        Durée
        };


          
\draw (Abonné.north east) to [bend left] node[midway, above] {0,1} (Adhère.west);
\draw (Adhère.east) to [bend left] node[midway, above] {0,1} (Club.west);
\draw (Abonné.east) to [bend right] node[midway, below left] {0,1} (Evènement.west);
\draw (Evènement.east) to [bend right] node[midway, below right] {0,1} (Club.west);
\draw (Evènement.west) to [bend left] node[midway, below right] {0,1} (Activité.east);


\end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Modèle E/A concernant le déroulement d'une année scolaire dans une université}
  
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Say your node is named A, then A.0==A.east, A.90==A.north, A.15 … you‘ll guess it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `nodename.angle` to specify the position on the edge of the node where your line should start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[draw,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=2cm] (Abonné) {Abonné};
      \draw (Abonné.25) -- ++ (2,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]